# Getting data to input into a spreadsheet by clicking on a button

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm struggling to get my Excel spreadsheet (2010) to do what I want, but I'm not sure its possible!

What I have is diagrams with numbers (with the numbers in circles) on sheet two, on sheet one I have VLOOKUPs waiting to input the appropriate data. What I want, is for the user to click on the circle containing whichever number, then for that number to be put in the first column of the sheet, thus causing the VLOOKUP to fill in the rest of the data. Any ideas? I'm trying to play about with macros but I've had no luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Jazz

EDIT: I've managed to get a macro to copy and paste the data to the correct column, what I now need is for the macro to put the pasted data into the next blank cell in the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try a command like the following:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

After you have unlocked the worksheet and copied the data, have the VB code go to the active sheet, and paste your data in row that follows the last used row in the worksheet. If you can weave something like this in, you will be able to avoid indexing the rows with a number. You will also be able to deal with the case that there are empty rows sprinkled within column A in this case.

Comment: It works! Is there a way to force it to input the data into column A? For instance, I was just playing around with it, and had left cell F7 clicked, and when back to my buttons, and when I clicked, it input the data into F7, then put itself in the next free A row.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Excellent! Very glad that  you were able to solve the problem!